# Shut-down script on Windows to delete a registry key?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, registry

**EDIT:** This was formerly more explicitly titled: - "**Best solution to stop Kontiki's KHOST.EXE from loading automatically at start-up on Windows XP?**"

Essentially, whenever the **[40D](http://www.channel4.com/4od/index.html)** application is run it sets up **khost.exe** to automatically start-up with Windows.  This is annoying as it increases my boot up time by a couple of minutes and I don't even use the P2P aspect of 4OD anyway.

The registry keys that are set are:

```
Command: C:\Program Files\Kontiki\KHost.exe -all
Description: kdx
Location: HKU\S-1-5-21-1757981266-1960408961-839522115-1003\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
Name: kdx
Setting ID:
User: LAPTOP\Me

Command: "C:\Program Files\Kontiki\KHost.exe" -all
Description: 4oD
Location: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
Name: 4oD
Setting ID:
User: All Users
```

I'm assuming some kind of **start-up** or **shut-down** **script** to delete these registry keys would be the best solution, but I'm not that up with **.vbs** or **.bat** scripting or where I'd put them to automatically run at an appropriate time.

I know there is a **[TV On-Demand Monitor application](http://odmonitor.blogspot.com/)**, but I don't really need to be running yet another process, I just need to delete the registry keys as I describe above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the vb script you would use something like this:

```
Dim WSHShell
Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'repeat the line below for each key to delete 
WSHShell.RegDelete "[Location of Key]"
```

Just drop the code into a text file and re-name it something like shutdown,vbs.

As for when to run it, if you are in a corporate environment you could use a group policy and set it as a machine shutdown script. Alternatively, see this page [here](http://www.msfn.org/board/lofiversion/index.php/t40945.html) about adding it manually

Answer (score 2):

**What I ended up doing in the end:**

**1)** Stopped **40D** from the task tray with a **right-click** > **exit** which terminated the **Khost.exe** process.

**2)** Opened **Start** > **All Programs** > **Administrative Tools** > **Services** and stopped **KService** then set the **Startup Type** to '**Manual**'.

**3)** Created a ***ShutdownScript.vbs*** with the following content:

```
Set SH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

RemoveRegKey "HKU\S-1-5-21-1757981266-1960408961-839522115-1003\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\kdx"
RemoveRegKey "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\kdx"
RemoveRegKey "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\4oD"

Shutdown

Set Shell = Nothing
Set SH = Nothing
WScript.Quit

Sub RemoveRegKey(sKey)
    On Error Resume Next
    SH.RegDelete sKey
End Sub

Sub Shutdown()
    SH.Run "shutdown -s -t 1", 0, TRUE
End Sub
```

**4)** Put a **shortcut** to the script in my **Start Menu** and now use that to shut the PC down.

Now **40D** will work when I need it, and all I have to do is quit it and shutdown with the script to stop it auto-starting everytime I boot up the PC.

**THANKS FOR ALL YOUR HELP WITH THIS! :)**

Answer (score 1):

Why not just copy the executable to some other name, and put a do-nothing exe in its place. Then change your shortcuts to the copied and renamed EXE. If the program is sensitive to its name, then point your shortcuts to a VBS file to temporarily rename the EXE file.

Answer (score 1):

Another method:

Create a VBS file that runs the program and then deletes the registry keys.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 

objShell.Exec("C:\Program Files\Kontiki\KHost.exe")

strRoot = "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\4oD" 
strDelete = objShell.RegDelete(strRoot) 
...
```

And point your shortcuts at that.

Answer (score 1):

Should I suggest you give a try to AutoIt (http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/), a freeware scripting language designed for automating the Windows GUI and general scripting.

If you choose to use it, the AutoIt code for your need would be a 2-liner:

```
RegDelete("YourKey", "YourValue");
ShutDown(1);
```

And you can compile it into a standalone exe that can run on any computer (no runtime library needed)